# Android and Custom ListView

Tags: android, listview

i have custom list view that each row has one TextView and one ImageView.
I want when user clicked on row, the image of row changed.

Following is the code which I have written.

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

    img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageseleckted);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(id), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (SmsMultiCasting.selectedRow[(int)id] == 0) {
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.tik);
        SmsMultiCasting.selectedRow[(int)id] = 1;
    } else {
        SmsMultiCasting.selectedRow[(int)id] = 0;
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.uncheck);
    }
}
```

But when I clicked on row 10 next row and 10 next row and so on also change the picture,

How can define that only selected row change image?

Comment: Why don't you use ImageView onClickListener instead of onItemClickListener of list

Answer (score 1):

The best suited design pattern here is to use ViewHolder. You can handle click event using view holder. Custom Adapter code below

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList listData;

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList listData) {
        this.listData = listData;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.headlineView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.reporterNameView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.reporter);
            holder.reportedDateView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.headlineView.setText(listData.get(position).getHeadline());
        holder.reporterNameView.setText("By, " + listData.get(position).getReporterName());
        holder.reportedDateView.setText(listData.get(position).getDate());


        holder.headlineView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // handle your click event here
        }
        });


        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView headlineView;
        TextView reporterNameView;
        TextView reportedDateView;
    }

}
```

You may have look at the complete tutorial here [Android ListView Tutorial](http://javatechig.com/android/android-listview-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

When your adapter gives you next row it tries to re-use some old, unneeded view. So, when such view is being reused, it keeps all the changes made before until they are cancelled manually in the adapter. Thus, each 10(it depends on list size, as I can see) rows share actually the same view.

Comment: @user2580975 in the adapter in `getView` method you should detect if the row can be reused or not(if it's changed, it is probably can not be reused), and by determining that you either re-use old view or inflate a new one

Answer (score 0):

In your onItemClick once the user selects any row,you have to reset all the images to the default state and then change the image of the selected row .Else as u have already done,set or reset the clicked position in an array and call notifydatasetchanged.Then in your getView() u have to check the array and set the corresponding image.

Answer (score 0):

Views are recycled in ListViews, Check the following post its a different way but should work.. [Listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17427881/how-to-change-the-image-resource-of-a-item-clicked-in-a-list-view)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the text in your OnItemClickListener in your list view and get the text of your selected row. and use this to change the image. See the link below:

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208827/how-to-extract-the-text-from-the-selected-item-on-the-listview)